# winXP to VM because of hardware changes in 21century 2020/2021

Tags: linux, windows-xp, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine

its 2021; maja where wrong with 2012, we are still alive but corona! :-/

i still have a migration problem:

A native winXP needs to become to a VM because of hardware changes. what to do? how to?

i still have an old pc including an old debian linux and also (from very first time) a windows xp on it. i have serveral VM using virtualbox (currently 6.1) but never tried to move a nativ winxp from disk to a VM. the web is full of infomation but mostly it lacks for the future (code freeze for the VM also? -> run xp in an old VM container of a new VM software?).

What works currently? The old hardware must go but i still need the old windows xp for some data/functions or features. (Data is mostly already migrated to a shared storrage but not complete. thats why)

Big thanks for hints!

Kind regards
florian

Answer (score 2):

There are many P2V programs available, some even freeware like [disk2vhd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd) . There are also backup programs that let you restore to dissimilar hardware, hence letting you migrate hardware. I use since years [EaseUS Todo Backup Free 3.5](https://www.filehorse.com/download-easeus-todo-backup/8957/). It is the last version that is freeware including commercial use.

Install Todo Backup on a Windows 7 PC, download the packages to create a Windows PE image and create a WindowsPE .iso image with Todo Backup Free 3.5. It is around 180MB big. You can burn it to CD or create a bootable USB with [Yumi](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).

Make a backup of the physical computer by partition. Then create an iso image of that .pbd file with a cd burn program like [CDBurnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se/en/home) or any other free or paid software.

To restore your backup in a virtual machine, mount the iso image of Todo Backup free in the first CD drive and the iso image of the backup image (.pbd file) in the second CD drive. Make sure the virtual machine has enough ram. Since the Windows PE is build on Windows 7 32-bit, it would be good to allocate 1GB RAM. You can reduce that to what ever Windows XP will use after restore. As OS I would still choose Windows XP and not Windows 7. Set the virtual machine to boot from first CD (Todo Backup free). Don't forget to press a key, if the hard disk of the virtual machine is not empty. Inside restore, select to restore partitions, select the second CD drive and then your .pbd backup file. And then select the option to restore to dissimilar hardware. You can resize the output partition size, if needed.

The "restore to dissimilar hardware" part takes care of any hardware incompatibilities, that may arise.

You will need to activate Windows again and you should install the guest extensions to install missing drivers.

PS. Make sure you have all VT-x/AMD-V option active, or it will be very slow or not work at all. You could also connect a USB Drive to the virtual machine with the .pbd backup file, but that requires to install VirtualBox extension pack to use USB 2.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot on this! I will give it a try!